# Redirect 301 www.www.example.com

Tags: linux, apache, seo, http-status-code-301

I'm using LAMP server, and I need to redirect requests like:

**www.www.example.com to www.example.com and other variations like (wwww.example.com, etc)**

I know I can do it in .htaccess, but I don't know the regular expression that I should use to represent all these possibilities.

Or there is any diferent approach, comming from the vhosts?

Comment: Just to let you know: There is a standard that defines that www.example.org should be used for example URIs.

Comment: @Lennart are you serious? who wrote that?!

Comment: @Cogsy see http://www.example.com/

Comment: That would be RFC 2606 -- http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2606.txt -- the idea is to not use arbitrary domains on people since who knows what would be there (domain squatting crud) if people try them out when reading your examples. It's only a little funny. :-)

Comment: I'm wondering why you want to do this... if the user types in a different server address, they probably want that other address.  Either that or they made a mistake, and it should be their job to correct the mistake.  Next you'll be spellchecking the paths of your URLs and trying to correct them...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like:

```
# force www IN URL
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
# END force www IN URL
```

Basically anything that's *not* www.example.com will get redirect 301'd.

Answer (score 2):

See this article for implementing "wildcard subdomains." You're going to need to implement both an .htaccess and modifying the Vhosts.

http://www.easymodrewrite.com/example-subdomains

If you're interested in only limiting it to "www.www," "wwww.," and the other examples above, you can easily do so with some server-side coding (which makes it more flexible than implementing more .htaccess code). Just detect what the subdomain is, and redirect where you want.

Answer (score 0):

Using name based virtual hosts in Apache you can do this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias wwww.example.com www.www.example.com [space seperated list]

    Redirect / http://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Redirect can take a parameter to specify the type of redirect.

Comment: Downside of this approach is you have to know the typos in advance.